# Should this edit form have fewer items than the add-new form?

Tags: forms

I have an edit user form with the following fields: name, alternative name, gender, birthday, country, address, mobile phone, telephone, fax, email, Line, Facebook, and WeChat.

Should the add new user form have fewer fields, optionally letting the user fill more information in the edit form? Is this a common pattern?

I ask because I feel it'd be a drag to fill all the optional info just to create a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating a new user, I would display only the fields that are absolutely necessary for registration, to make the on-boarding as easy and fast and possible.

All unnecessary fields I would leave for "edit profile".

I'm, sure I've seen some websites that have the similar pattern.